# How to accept image as user input in python

Tags: python

I writing a program on image processing. At the moment, I have included, the image name in the program. 
I am trying out, if its possible, for the user to input the image, so the program is able to serve any image.

There is a way to accept user input in python, but how can i accept an image as a input, the path the leads to the image.??

first few lines of the program, looking for way, to accept the image  "house1.jpg" from the user. The path for this image in my pc is "C:\Python27\house1"

```
import Image
#open the images
im1 = Image.open("house1.jpg").convert("L")
im2 = Image.open("house2.jpg").convert("L")

im1.save(house1.jpg")
im2.save(house2.jpg")

sizex, sizey = im1.size
```

....

Answer (score 4):

```
import sys

im1 = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
```

and pass the image on the command line: `python script.py house1.jpg`. This extends to multiple command line arguments/images in the obvious way; read about [`argv`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv) in the library docs.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input)

The code would look like this:

```
 imageFileName = raw_input("enter the name of the image file: ")
```

Comment: I've submitted a bogus edit, please delete if you can (I can't rollback)

Answer (score -3):

In python we have a package named Pillow that can be used to read and edit images.
So, if we are interested in opening a file in python we can do this as --

`from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(path) #path is the path of image file`

For other options you can follow the Pillow documentation
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/